# Why does the Java regex ".*[two].*" match "[one]"?

Tags: java, regex, string

Why does `String.matches` return `true` when two values are in `[]` brackets?

```
System.out.println("[one]".matches("(?i).*" + "[two]" + ".*"));
   //Why does it return true? Shouldn't "[]" be treated as value?
System.out.println("one".matches("(?i).*" + "two" + ".*"));//OK - prints false

System.out.println("[one]".equals("[two]"));//OK - prints false
System.out.println("one".equals("two"));//OK - prints false
```

Comment: `[]` denote a character class inside of a regular expression. Since you are using the `matches()` method which accepts a regular expression, that is what they are being interpreted as. Try adding a \ in front of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex:  .*     [two]     .*
Match:  "["     "o"    "ne]"
```

The rectangular brackets have to be quoted.

Try `"[one]".matches("(?i).*" + Pattern.quote("[two]") + ".*")` instead.

Answer (score 9):

Beacuase `[two]` matches one of the letters t, w or o which is in the string `"[one]"`

Answer (score 6):

```
System.out.println("[one]".matches("(?i).*[two].*"));
```

prints `true` because the `o` of the [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[two]` matches the `o` in `one`. The following `.*` matches `ne` - Voilà, successful match!

In a regular expression, `[abc]` means "one of the characters `a`, `b` or `c`".

```
System.out.println("[one]".matches("(?i).*\\[two].*"));
```

will print `false` because now the brackets are treated literally. Not that this regex makes a lot of sense, though.

Answer (score 1):

`[two]` matches one of the letters in the square brackets, i.e. `'t', 'w', and 'o'`
To match the square brackets also, you need to escape it like `\[two\]`